# In PHP, session variable is not storing the value. What is wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, html

The following is a sample PHP code. I am expecting the session variable 't' to increment its value when update function is called. However, when I run the code I keep getting the output as Value: 1. What should I do so that the value is stored into the session variable?

```
<?php
session_start();    
if(!isset($_SESSION['t'])) {
    $_SESSION['t'] = 0;
}
?>
<div id="test" class="test"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    function update() {

        var ct = "<?php echo $_SESSION['t'] += 1 ?>";

        <?php echo "Value: " . $_SESSION['t']; ?>;

        $("#test").html(ct);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
       setInterval('update()', 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: From what I see, it seems as if you're trying to copy-paste code from various sources. I recommend sitting down and learning to program properly.

Comment: Remember the SESSION lives on the server and so does PHP. But Javascript runs on the browser.

Comment: No @Raahim. I am trying to store a value inside a session variable on one page and access it on another page. Above is a simple code that I wrote to understand the working of session variables. I don't understand why the above code does not work. The first page updates the value of the session variable every few minutes. The second page does not show the updated value unless the page is refreshed and I don't want to refresh the page. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your PHP code that increments the session value is run only once – on the server. “Wrapping” it into a JavaScript function doesn’t change that one bit. And the JS code you are outputting doesn’t seem to make sense either – it should generate a JavaScript error. So @Raahim is rather right – you need to learn some basics of the techniques you are trying to use first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `session_start()` at the very top of your script, before any output

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // if you automatically set SESSION['t'] to 0 when the page loads, it will never increment
    // check if the SESSION exists, and if it doesn't, then we create it
    if(!isset($_SESSION['t'])) {
        $_SESSION['t'] = 0;
    }
?>


<div id="test" class="test"></div>

<!-- it's recommended to load scripts at the end of the page -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    function update() {
        // you had some formatting issues in here...

        // shortcut: using +=1 will take the current value of $_SESSION['t'] and add 1
        var ct = "<?php echo $_SESSION['t'] += 1 ?>";

        <?php echo "Value: " . $_SESSION['t']; ?>;

        $("#test").html(ct);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
       setInterval('update()', 1000);
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE:
This is an example that will do what I think you're looking for. It will display the value of `$_SESSION['t']` when the page is loaded, and then increment the value of `$_SESSION['t']` every time the update button is clicked. There is no error checking, this is just a very simple example to show you how this works.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['t'])) {
        $_SESSION['t'] = 0;
    }
?>


<div id="test" class="test"></div>

<button type="button" id="update">Update</button>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // create the ct varaible
        var ct = <?php echo $_SESSION['t']; ?>;

        // display the value in the #test div
        $("#test").text(ct);

        // when the update button is clicked, we call ajax.php
        $("#update").click(function(){
            $.post("ajax.php", function(response){

                // display the returned value from ajax.php
                $("#test").text(response);
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

// increment the session by 1
$_SESSION['t'] += 1;

// return the result
echo $_SESSION['t'];
```

Comment: Thanks! But the value does not update unless the page is refreshed.

Comment: Correct, that's what you code is telling it to do. You will need to write a function or event handler to perform the update `onclick`, or whatever...

Comment: Why can't the jquery do it? The jquery is calling the function every second. You were helpful. I didn't downvote you.

Comment: The PHP SESSION and jQuery are two different things, as explained in the comments above. If you want to store the incremental value back into the PHP SESSION will need to write a function to update the PHP SESSION via ajax, which is something you do not want to do every second.

Comment: Just updated my answer to give you an example. Perhaps this is what you're looking for?...